# "su - username -c env" Execution is missing environment variable

Tags: linux, environment-variables

When executing "su - username -c env" under the root user, there are very few environment variables. If directly su - username and then execute env, there are many environment variables. As a result, when the script needs to call the script under username under root user. There will be a lack of variables and cannot be executed.
such as:

```
root@davinci-mini:/home/HwHiAiUser# su - HwHiAiUser -c '/home/HwHiAiUser/zhuangzelong/zzlstart.sh'
root@davinci-mini:/home/HwHiAiUser# /home/HwHiAiUser/zhuangzelong/vision1/vision/build/devel/lib/vision_ros_node/vision_ros_node: error while loading shared libraries: libge_executor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? How to solve it

I had tried:

```
su  HwHiAiUser -c '/home/HwHiAiUser/zhuangzelong/zzlstart.sh'
```

and

```
su - HwHiAiUser -c '/home/HwHiAiUser/zhuangzelong/zzlstart.sh'
```

Both of them don't work. But when I try:

```
su HwHiAiUser
/home/HwHiAiUser/zhuangzelong/zzlstart.sh
```

It works.

Comment: `su $user -c $command` starts a non-interactive shell that does not source your interactive rc script. Whereas `su $user` starts an interactive shell which does source your rc script.